# what is the right way to use forwardRef with withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-forwardref, react-hoc

I just tried to use forwardRef with a withRouter(mycomponent)  like this :

```js
export default function App() {

  const childRef = useRef();
  const childWithRouteRef = useRef();

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("childWithRouteRef",childWithRouteRef);
    childRef.current.say();
    childWithRouteRef.current.say();
  })


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Child ref={childRef}/>
      <ChildWithRoute_ ref={childWithRouteRef}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        say: () => {
      console.log("hello")
        },
  }));

  return <div>Child</div>
})

const ChildWithRoute = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        say: () => {
      console.log("hello")
        },
  }));

  return <div>ChildWithRoute</div>
})

const ChildWithRoute_ = withRouter(ChildWithRoute)
```

if I wrapped my component in a withRouter HOC, the ref will not working, it's always null. so how can I use forwardRef with a component wrapped in withRouter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Forwarding refs in higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components)

> ... refs will not get passed
>   through. That’s because `ref` is not a prop. Like `key`, it’s handled
>   differently by React. If you add a ref to a HOC, the ref will refer to
>   the outermost container component, not the wrapped component.

Looks as though the `withRouter` HOC doesn't yet forward refs. You can create your own little HOC to also forward a ref to the decorated-with-router component

```
const withRouterForwardRef = Component => {
  const WithRouter = withRouter(({ forwardedRef, ...props }) => (
    <Component ref={forwardedRef} {...props} />
  ));

  return forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <WithRouter {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />
  ));
};
```

Usage:

```
const ChildWithRoute = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    say: () => console.log("hello from child with route"),
  }));

  return <div>ChildWithRoute</div>;
})

const ChildWithRouteAndRef = withRouterForwardRef(ChildWithRoute);

...
<ChildWithRouteAndRef ref={childWithRouteRef} />
```

[image: Edit forwardRef - HOC]

After a quick google search I found this [issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6056), and based on the timestamps and last comment seems unlikely to be resolved. My above solution is similar to several approaches shared.